# adding values from a specific dictionary key to a new set

Tags: python, dictionary, set, key

New to Python.

I have a list of dictionaries (called data) with three keys ['name'], ['phoneNumber'] and ['street'].

I now want to append all the phone numbers to a new set.  Below is what I think it should be, but I am obviously wrong.

```
data= [{'name':'Bob', 'phoneNumber':'12345','street':'Yobbo'} #and so on
justPhoneNumbers = ()
for numbers in data['phoneNumber']
justPhoneNumbers.append
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data` is a list of dictionaries, then iterate over that list and then append the data

```
justPhoneNumbers = set() # Declare the set
for d in data:
    justPhoneNumbers.add(d['phoneNumber'])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data = [{'name': 'Bob', 'phoneNumber': '12345','street': 'Yobbo'}]
justPhoneNumbers = [x['phoneNumber'] for x in data]
```

For this solution duplicates are allowed. Use `set` if you want to get rid of duplicates.

```
justPhoneNumbers = set(justPhoneNumbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

for loop will loop through the list and give you list member one by one ('numbers') then you can access the dictionary element (" phoneNumber")

```
data= [{'name':'Bob', 'phoneNumber':'12345','street':'Yobbo'}]#and so on
justPhoneNumbers =[]
for numbers in data:
  justPhoneNumbers.append(numbers['phoneNumber'])
```

Comment: This does not work. Closing `]` of the list missing, indentation error in `for`-loop and appending to tuple...

Comment: I was in a hurry to post the code and busy in the editing .